# Ubuntu 22.04 missing some groups under /etc/group

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a VPS, but found some groups are missing: "sudo" and "adm". I have no issues with another VPS with Ubuntu 22.04 installed. Is it the problem with the Ubuntu image? Can I simply run "groupadd" to add those missing groups?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and yes, adding them (with gid's under 1000) works fine

```sh
addgroup -g 4 adm
addgroup -g 201 sudo
```